Can I tell people that I have put my trust in Allah about a matter, when in reality I am facing a lot of anxiety about that matter?
I am a 34 years old unmarried woman with no fall-backs/backups in life.  To cut a long story short, my career is also almost in a dumpster. It is sheerly the mercy of Allah that He is keeping me afloat, alhamdoliAllah.
So I do feel a lot of anxiety about things. It's a continuous battle where fears and negative thoughts come in my mind, and I consciously tell myself (of course alhamdoliAllah) that Allah is so merciful that He will definitely take care of my and unfold the best plan for me, just like He has taken care of me so far.
When I meet people for a few minutes or hours in social gatherings, they give me a lot of unsolicited and superficial advise (which is not even intended at suggesting a solution for the challenges I face, but it is rather talk for the sake of talk), without thinking that if I could solve my problems, I would have done that.
My question is that is it OK if I keep telling the people that I have put my trust in Allah and Allah will make the best way out for me, I am sure of it (while in reality I do face anxiety related to these matters)?

In the of Allah
Firstly I ask Allah to grant you a spouse and ease your worries
Second be grateful for what you have and that will ease your worries
عن أبي هريرة رضي الله عنه عن النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم قال: «انظروا إلى من هو أسفل منكم، ولا تنظروا إلى من هو فوقكم، فهو أجدر أن لا تَزْدَرُوا نعمة الله عليكم».
[صحيح] - [متفق عليه، وهذا لفظ مسلم]
Abu Hurayrah (may Allah be pleased with him) reported that the Prophet (may Allah's peace and blessings be upon him) said: "Look at those who are below you, and do not look at those who are above you, for that is more likely to hold you back from belittling the blessings that Allah has bestowed upon you."
3rd recite this dua in the evening and morning
للّهُـمَّ إِنِّـي أسْـأَلُـكَ العَـفْوَ وَالعـافِـيةَ في الدُّنْـيا وَالآخِـرَة ، اللّهُـمَّ إِنِّـي أسْـأَلُـكَ العَـفْوَ وَالعـافِـيةَ في ديني وَدُنْـيايَ وَأهْـلي وَمالـي ، اللّهُـمَّ اسْتُـرْ عـوْراتي وَآمِـنْ رَوْعاتـي ، اللّهُـمَّ احْفَظْـني مِن بَـينِ يَدَيَّ وَمِن خَلْفـي وَعَن يَمـيني وَعَن شِمـالي ، وَمِن فَوْقـي ، وَأَعـوذُ بِعَظَمَـتِكَ أَن أُغْـتالَ مِن تَحْتـي
‘O Allah, I ask You for pardon and well-being in this life and the next. O Allah, I ask You for pardon and well-being in my religious and worldly affairs, and my family and my wealth. O Allah, veil my weaknesses and set at ease my dismay. O Allah, preserve me from the front and from behind and on my right and on my left and from above, and I take refuge with You lest I be swallowed up by the earth.’

Be consistent in the above

And Allah knows best with regards to your situation

JazakAllah khair. I'll inshaAllah incorporate the supplication you shared in my routine. I'll inshaAllah be grateful for so much Allah has blessed me with, alhamdoliAllah.
However, despite my appreciation and gratitude for your advice,  I was perhaps not able to communicate my question well. My question is that is it OK/ permissible if I say I put my trust in Allah and keep telling myself this, to fight the fears and doubt in my heart; or am I living in fool's paradise?
